# SML specification for IntListSet structure

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
val x =  IntListSet.listItems(IntListSet.addList(IntListSet.empty,[1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

If you run this in SML, it returns

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6] : IntListSet.item list
```

I want it to return

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6] : Int list
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need not do anything. `IntListSet.item` is just an alias for `Int.int`, so your function already returns the correct type.